# How to reduce the fragility of jasmine unit tests in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Angular recommends using Jasmine for their testing framework, but the more I work with Jasmine the more I worry about the fragility of my unit tests. Currently, I am using stubs and spies to provide dependencies to the functions, but I am worried about how the tests will behave when functionality is added to the codebase.

For example, when making spies using `dependency = jasmine.createSpyObj(['method1', 'method2'])`, calling dependency.method3() when implementing a new feature would cause the tests to fail because method3 does not exists on the spies.

The same applies if I use stubs as described in [the angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency), as I would need to create stub functions using jasmine.spyOn or similar methods.

Ideally, this case should not result in failure and makes my tests incredibly fragile. I can resolve this by mocking the entire class interface, but this is unideal.

Is there any way of avoiding this?

Comment: Why would you call method3 in method2 test? Scope your tests!

Comment: Wouldn't you want a test to fail if you add a new feature and didn't add it to any tests? Sounds like a win to me.

Comment: `spyOn` does not create stub. It creates proxy of live object.

Comment: @Antoniossss If I added a new feature, it shouldn't cause the existing tests to break as they are testing different aspects of the application. However, a simple success case test (and all others for the function) would fail if I needed to add another side effect to the function.

Comment: If you are changing the contract, tests must be changed as well - it kind of natural.